# Wordpress site super admin mess

Tags: wordpress

My wordpress network have 4 blogs. One day, one user can't visit his dashboard after login because strange no enough permission problem. I make a bad decision, give him super user permission(it's not big deal to us). Then he can visit his dashboard, but the old super user can't visit the site dashboard. I use the new super user account visit site dashboard, it display only the new account as super user, but the super user number is two.

I checked the database, in table wp_sitemeta, the admin_user_id still point to the old one, and the value of site_admins is  a:2:{i:0;s:6:"old super user name";i:1;s:5:"new super user name";}. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

try to use the new super user account, whoever it is, to log in and go to network admin->user section. choose the older super user account and go to the profile page, you can grant the old super role back.

**x Grant this user super admin privileges for the Network.**

Comment: Actually there are two super user in network admin panel, but I only can see the new one and only the new one marked as super user, it means I can not use wordpress dashboard fix anything.